# Where exactly did they send Rin?

Tags: little-busters

***Heavy spoilers warning.*** This question is based on the VN, it should be applicable to the anime, though I'm not sure.

---

In Rin's 2nd route, she is sent to another school where

> many students died in a bus crash, and the rest are traumatized as a result. Rin is supposedly sent to help them.

However, as we know,

> the bus crash actually happened to them.

With that in mind, where is Rin actually sent?

> The place she is sent to does not exist, how does Kyousuke create something that should be an entirely different school with different people? Did he at all? What does Rin actually experience there? It breaks her mind as we can see in Refrain, but I don't know what it actually is that she experiences there.

Comment: we don't know where she was sent, it is any one of the school near their locality and about Rin, she felt the loneliness, separation from the group, which made Rin to suffer. We know Rin's characteristic and behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyousuke is akin to the DM in a Dungeons and Dragons session. He can create virtually anything from the "merging of the subconscious of all of his friends". In that particular do-over (Rin route 1), Kyousuke assumes that Riki and Rin have gone through enough (the routes of the other girls) such that they are strong enough to be apart.

Recall that Rin is extremely reliant on others emotionally, and Kyousuke, thinking that he is almost out of power to continue recreating the world (he isn't), creates a separate fictional school and sends Rin there to test her. Unfortunately, Rin isn't as strong as Kyousuke thought she was. Kyousuke set it up such that Rin initially could not even come back on the weekends, but after persuasion through Riki, he allowed it, and even that wasn't enough for Rin to grow independent.

Her extreme shyness and fear of strangers causes her to become alienated in her other school as she cannot even manage to respond to basic greetings. Kyousuke thinks that this will push her to get better, but instead Rin just falls apart. After that, as you know, Riki runs away with Rin, angering Kyousuke who thinks that Rin will never get better as long as she is reliant on Riki. Kyousuke sends the police after them and the trauma of them being forcefully separated breaks Rin completely. Kyousuke sees that he has failed and resets the world once more, becoming mopey Kyousuke.